# Using Unicode characters with Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-xe2

I'm looking at converting one of our applications to Delphi XE2 and generally take the opportunity to bring it up to date.

One of the features of the application is a StringGrid that displays a number of check marks in a couple of columns.  To achieve this the grid is actually 2 aligned grids - the second of which is setup with the font as Wingdings in order to display the check marks.

Am I wrong in thinking that I should be able to use something like a TListView and use the checkmark char (U+2713) alongside the rest of the text...  If so how the heck do I do this?

Do I need to set the font to Wingdings for that column?  Does this need to be in OnDraw?

Am I barking up the wrong tree...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`File->New->VCL Forms application`

In the `Component Palette`, expand the `Win32` tab and choose `TListView`, and drop it on the form.

Right-click the newly added `TreeView1`, and choose `Items Editor...` from the context menu.

Click `New Item`. Type in any text (for instance `x Testing`, using the 'x' as a placeholder for now).

Start the Windows `Character Map` application (Start button, type `Chara` in the search box, or `Start->Programs->Accessories->Character Map`). Change the font to `Arial Unicode MS`, and navigate to the character you want (it's in there).

Click the character, and then the `Copy` button. Switch back to the IDE, select the `x` placeholder you put in the edit, and hit <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> to paste the character you just chose from `Character Map`. You should now see your check mark (or whatever character you chose), followed by `Testing`.

(The steps above are the two-minute process I followed to find out how to do this, and that quick experiment showed that you could.)

Comment: Excellent - seems like the issue was how / where to find the appropriate character.

Comment: @DanKelly: I agree. :-) The majority of the time I spent figuring this out was locating the character you described.